# Graphic Card and Power Supply Connectors?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I am looking at [this card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003A4H696) to purchase and it says that it requires a `Available standard power connector from power supply`

My question is - what is a `standard connector` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's from the AGP era, it will be a [standard 4-pin Molex power connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex).

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware they powered video cards off molex connectors. Pretty useful thing to know, if i need to work with an older system.